# Instance variable not passing to block

Tags: ruby

Trying to pass the @server varible to the bot object but it is not working. I'm new to Ruby and not sure what I'm not doing correctly here.

```
  require 'cinch'

    class ConnectIRC

        attr_accessor :server, :channel, :nick, :realname

      def initialize(server, channel, nick, realname)
        @server = server
        @channel = channel
        @nick = nick
        @realname = realname
      end

      bot = Cinch::Bot.new do
        configure do |c|
          c.server = @server
        end
      end

      bot.start

    end
```

Comment: Little suggestion,   write it as `attr_accessor :server, :channel, :nick, :realname` for redundancy.

Comment: instance variable `@server` available only in the scope of `ConnectIRC` class

Comment: @server won't be available outside the class. Small suggestion, move that block inside the method inside ConnectIRC class then it will work

Comment: So how should I scope server so that it will be available to the bot method? I'm new to Ruby

Comment: move the `bot` initialization into the class or you can intialize an instance of that class and access the `server` variable on that instance

Comment: Moved bot into the class but Var is still not getting passed correctly.

Comment: which var are you reffering to @Brian

Comment: What is your `ConnectIRC` class supposed to do? Is it merely a container to store `server`, `channel,` `nick` and `realname` or should it also wrap / encapsulate access to the `Cinch::Bot` instance?

Comment: Shouldn't the bot code go inside the `initialize` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
require 'cinch'

class ConnectIRC

    attr_accessor :server, :channel, :nick, :realname

  def initialize(server, channel, nick, realname)
    @server = server
    @channel = channel
    @nick = nick
    @realname = realname
  end
end

@irc = ConneectIRC.new(server,channel,nick,realname) 

bot = Cinch::Bot.new do
    configure do |c|
      c.server = @irc.server
    end
  end

  bot.start
```